# How to install elementary-xfce theme

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, elementary

i am trying to make xubuntu 14.04 to look like elementary os.

I have found this repo https://github.com/shimmerproject/elementary-xfce, but have no idea how to *actually* apply this theme to my system.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

elementary-xfce is actually packaged in the xubuntu-icon-theme package in Ubuntu. This icon theme is used by default in Xubuntu. To apply it in 14.04, do the following.

1. Click on the Applications menu.
2. Click on the Settings icon.
3. Go to Appearance.
4. Select the Icons tab.
5. Choose any of the elementary-xfce variants. The icon theme will be applied immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Xubuntu Technical Leader Sean Davis.